# Should reputation points be calculated via a sliding time window?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Points are about reputation, and *reputation should be about skills, experience,  problem solving potential, invested work, commitment*, etc. This is a very strong goal of SO I think, because this is one of the things that establishes its value.

It definitely should not feel like a collecting competition, and the luck, the early bird effect, and the good collector sense should not play a role. Although there is nothing wrong with these factors in many areas in real life, they are not appropriate when we would like to measure (objectively) one's professional reputation.

For example, the early share holders of IBM are billionaires now. I am happy for them, many things in the world work like that and we are OK with that.  For SO reputation this simply does not work, as it goes against one of the current main goals: measuring skills.

We all see two-liner questions like *"how can I find a substring..."* (I intentionally do not link any). Only this question from six years ago is worth 15k. You will not be surprised the answer is worth more than 55K.

A simple method could solve this, and is applied in many systems where competency and reputation measurement is the goal: after some time the achievements become obsolete and do not count. The industry-leading IT companies' certification systems work this way. Outsourcing portals, where measuring skill, commitment and competency is essential, also work this way.

Comment: *"one of the current main goal: Measure skills."* - that is not mentioned in the help (http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), so why do you say that? Also, see the UberMeta dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155862/248731

Comment: @jonsharpe: Yes it _was_ not the goal. However the real life practice overwrote it. See the job market aspect here

Comment: What *"job market aspect"*? I can't imagine anyone basing more than a small part of their evaluation of a candidate on whether they've earned enough unicorn points yet (and I wouldn't want to work for anyone who took them more seriously).

Comment: Me neither :-), at least we agree on something. Btw that'is about my point

Comment: @g.pickardou So your point is that we should completely change what reputation means and how it's calculated because a few people who have jobs that the kinds of people SO wants to attract shouldn't be interested in might be using rep in ways that they shouldn't because they aren't taking the time to understand the meaning of the primary metric they're using in hiring candidates?  Sorry, but that just makes no sense.

Comment: @Servy: Good point, but no. Without aging achievements it does not work for _any_ goal. Try with your answer. How can you use this system for trust? Just because one answered 2 lines, and have 55k, why she/he can be more trusted than me, who just with this question invested more effort and proved more commitment for the site, and also taking the minuses.

Comment: @g.pickardou that's a good argument, *if* you can find someone who only got rep from trivial Qs/As a long time ago and is now misusing their privileges.

Comment: @g.pickardou As I said; it's a loose approximation for trust.  There are unusual cases where someone's reputation doesn't accurately represent how much we would like to trust them, so it shouldn't be given *too* much weight.  Even so, it *is* a useful approximation, as computing a highly accurate metric for how much trust a user deserves isn't really possible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes I evaluated your point _before_ I decided to to ask about this. She/he got 55K, but this is almost 90 percent of the total points. Again: This is not about persons this is about the system, and my simple recommendation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It has happened before, but it's quite rare.  It's why we have mods; to deal with the exceptional situations that come up in a largely community moderated site.

Comment: btw: If anyone disagree with me (even all), that does not mean it is a bad question.. The question could be good, especially if there is a clear answer.

Comment: @g.pickardou nobody has said it's a bad question - [voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: One point - I doubt that anyone *actually* got 55K from a single answer. Highly-upvoted answers are very likely to have received a lot of votes which contributed no rep due to the rep cap.

Comment: @JonSkeet [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13161/mattshane) is a user with over 21k rep that has only made one post.  It's not 55k, but it's still a *lot* of rep for only having made one post.  It's not the post that has earned a user the most rep, but it is the user with the most rep that has only made one post.

Comment: @Servy: Right - but that's instructive in terms of showing that the post has 4246 upvotes, but has still only resulted in 21k rep. I suspect the OP saw a post with ~5500 upvotes, and assumed that translated into 55k rep. In most cases (where there are other answers involved) the actual rep gained would probably be an even smaller proportion of the "cap-less" rep.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, but the idea that there are outliers where a user has made a very small number of posts and earned very large numbers of rep, such that the privileges given to them aren't representative of the actual trust they've earned or their knowledge of how to use those tools properly, is true.  It's just that it's sufficiently rare as to be manageable, even though it has happened.

Comment: @Servy: Yup, completely agree on that part. But if someone's going to try to use actual data to make a point, it helps if the data is accurate to start with :)

Comment: Open the sliding window, throw out the old users.  Defenestration is too good for them, but it will do at a pinch..

Comment: Firstly my bad, but there is much buzz what oversounds the main point, at least the point I was intended to express. Again, it is also my bad to talking about reputation "meaning" etc. The point is (regardless what is the meaning or purpose of the reputation): A sliding time window, or "aging" could definitely help to make it more correlated to an actual value, let it be "trust level" or anything else.

Comment: @JonSkeet In the case of that user, the only thing they did was ask a (broad and today summarily downvoted and closed) question. And they got 21k rep for that. Pretty amazing, huh?

Comment: @Magisch: And rare, too. I think it's worth making the rules work broadly, knowing that there will be occasional exceptional cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't proposing a rule change. Just pointing out there's legit outliers in the current system

Comment: Interestingly no one talking about the point: Regardless what is the meaning of the "points", time erodes it. It does not make sense if a person has silence of say 5 years, still his reputation just grow (instead of eroding). This makes points behave similar to an investment or gold, which obviously not the goal.

Answer (score 14):

Reputation isn't there to measure someone's skills, so the fact that it doesn't do a good job of measuring skill is entirely expected.

It's there to be a loose approximation of how much the site can trust them, which is why it's used to determine which moderation features are available to the user.

Comment: Well, respectfully disagree. 2 reasosns: 1) This is a developer portal, and reputation word has a meaning in this context. 2) SO more and more about find jobs/employees. So reputation should have this value.

Comment: @g.pickardou The fact that you want it to mean something that it doesn't mean at all, doesn't mean much to anyone.  Like I said, that's not what reputation is designed represent, and it's computed accordingly.  If someone is hiring a person based on a number on a site without understanding what that number even means, without understanding where it comes from, and without realizing that it in no way signifies how well they'll be able to do the job, then you probably don't want to work there.

Comment: This is not about me. Meaning of words is about a common agreement. Attach to a different meaning (what needs to be explained) is not a good practice

Comment: @g.pickardou and the *"common agreement"* is made clear in the help documentation. You are the one trying to attach different meaning to it.

Comment: @g.pickardou Words can have multiple meanings.  It's a sometimes unfortunate truth of human communication, and it's something that everyone needs to be mindful of at all times.  Context matters.  The meaning of words cannot be evaluated in isolation.